# Sorting on partition keys during INSERT INTO (Parquet) TABLE with Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, parquet, impala

I have an ETL job where I want to append data from a .csv file into an Impala table. Currently, I do this by creating a temporary external .csv table with the new data (in .csv.lzo format), after which it is inserted into the main table.

The query I use looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE main_table
PARTITION(yr, mth)
SELECT
    *,
    CAST(extract(ts, "year") AS SMALLINT) AS yr,
    CAST(extract(ts, "month") AS TINYINT) AS mth
FROM csv_table
```

where `main_table` is defined as follows (several columns truncated):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main_table (
    tid             INT,
    s1              VARCHAR,
    s2              VARCHAR,
    status          TINYINT,
    ts              TIMESTAMP,
    n1              DOUBLE,
    n2              DOUBLE,
    p               DECIMAL(3,2),
    mins            SMALLINT,
    temp            DOUBLE
)
PARTITIONED BY (yr SMALLINT, mth TINYINT)
STORED AS PARQUET
```

The data is on the order of a few GB (55 million rows with some 30 columns), and this takes over an hour to run. I was curious as to why this was the case (as this seems rather long for something that is essentially an append operation), and came across this in the query plan:

```
F01:PLAN FRAGMENT [HASH(CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT),CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT))] hosts=2 instances=2
|  Per-Host Resources: mem-estimate=1.01GB mem-reservation=12.00MB thread-reservation=1
WRITE TO HDFS [default.main_table, OVERWRITE=false, PARTITION-KEYS=(CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT),CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT))]
|  partitions=unavailable
|  mem-estimate=1.00GB mem-reservation=0B thread-reservation=0
|
02:SORT
|  order by: CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT) ASC NULLS LAST, CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT) ASC NULLS LAST
|  materialized: CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT), CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT)
|  mem-estimate=12.00MB mem-reservation=12.00MB spill-buffer=2.00MB thread-reservation=0
|  tuple-ids=1 row-size=1.29KB cardinality=unavailable
|  in pipelines: 02(GETNEXT), 00(OPEN)
|
01:EXCHANGE [HASH(CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT),CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT))]
|  mem-estimate=2.57MB mem-reservation=0B thread-reservation=0
|  tuple-ids=0 row-size=1.28KB cardinality=unavailable
|  in pipelines: 00(GETNEXT)
|
```

Apparently, most of the time and resources are spent sorting on the partition keys:

```
Operator       #Hosts  Avg Time  Max Time   #Rows  Est. #Rows  Peak Mem  Est. Peak Mem  Detail                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
02:SORT             2    17m16s    30m50s  55.05M          -1  25.60 GB       12.00 MB                                                                                                  
01:EXCHANGE         2   9s493ms  12s822ms  55.05M          -1  26.98 MB        2.90 MB  HASH(CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT),CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT)) 
00:SCAN HDFS        2  51s958ms     1m10s  55.05M          -1  76.06 MB      704.00 MB  default.csv_table
```

Why does Impala have to do this? Is there any way to partition the table without having to sort on the partition keys, or a way to speed it up in my case, where the entirety of the .csv files I'm trying to append has only 1 or 2 partition keys?

EDIT: It turns out that this is most likely because I'm using the Parquet file format. My question still applies though: is there a way to speed up the sort when I know there is little to no sorting actually required?

By comparison, an operation like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM csv_table WHERE extract(ts, "year") = 2018 AND extract(ts, "month") = 1` takes around 2-3 minutes, whereas the `ORDER BY` (as done during the insert) takes over an hour. This example only had the keys (2018,1) and (2018,2).

Comment: can you add table definition of your target table ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added it and realised that the sort is because I'm storing the table in the parquet file format, as explained here: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/12/faster-performance-for-selective-queries/. I'm still wondering how I could speed things up though.

Comment: do you see the same behavior creating the table partitioned and clustered ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but to my knowledge, Impala doesn't make use of clustered tables. Also, the blog post from my earlier comment states explicitly that the data is being sorted because of the parquet format. I was hoping for a solution somewhere along the lines of telling Impala that a sort isn't necessary (perhaps by inserting one partition at a time)

Comment: that is correct, but it is because your key distribution (used for partitions) is highly concentrated in 1 partition. If you enforce clustering adding a different column, I would assume that this will improve the performance

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have clarified earlier that my key distribution isn't actually skewed. I'm dumping data on a weekly basis into a huge table, so while the job only handles one or two partitions, the target table has rather evenly distributed partitions, made up to 6-8 files each.

Answer (score 1):

You can add hint to disable the sort stage.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE main_table
PARTITION(yr, mth)  /* +NOCLUSTERED */
SELECT
    *,
    CAST(extract(ts, "year") AS SMALLINT) AS yr,
    CAST(extract(ts, "month") AS TINYINT) AS mth
FROM csv_table
```

As explain here:[Optimizer Hints](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_hints.html)

> /* +CLUSTERED */ and /* +NOCLUSTERED */ Hints /* +CLUSTERED */ sorts
>   data by the partition columns before inserting to ensure that only one
>   partition is written at a time per node. Use this hint to reduce the
>   number of files kept open and the number of buffers kept in memory
>   simultaneously. This technique is primarily useful for inserts into
>   Parquet tables, where the large block size requires substantial memory
>   to buffer data for multiple output files at once. This hint is
>   available in Impala 2.8 or higher. Starting in Impala 3.0, /*
>   +CLUSTERED */ is the default behavior for HDFS tables.
>
> /* +NOCLUSTERED */ does not sort by primary key before insert. This
>   hint is available in Impala 2.8 or higher. Use this hint when
>   inserting to Kudu tables.
>
> In the versions lower than Impala 3.0, /* +NOCLUSTERED */ is the
>   default in HDFS tables.

Answer (score 0):

Impala does the sorting because you use dynamic partitioning. Especially with tables with oncomputed stats, impala is not very well at dynamic partitioning. I advise you to use hive in case of dynamic partitions. If you are not about to use hive, my advises are :

1. Do compute stats on the csv table before each insert into statements.
2. If the first step does not work well, use static partition for a few possible partitions, and run dynamic partition that is out of the possible ranges. For example; if there is one option of year and month:

> ```
> INSERT 
> INTO TABLE main_table
> PARTITION(yr=2019, mth=2)
> SELECT
>     *
> FROM csv_table where CAST(extract(ts, "year") AS SMALLINT)=2019 and CAST(extract(ts, "month") AS TINYINT)=2;  
> INSERT INTO TABLE main_table
> PARTITION(yr, mth)
> SELECT
>     *,
>     CAST(extract(ts, "year") AS SMALLINT),
>     CAST(extract(ts, "month") AS TINYINT)
> FROM csv_table where CAST(extract(ts, "year") AS SMALLINT)!=2019 and CAST(extract(ts, "month") AS TINYINT)!=2;
> ```

These statements shrink the set which dynamic partition would deal. And expected to decrease the total time spent.

Comment: I'll give (1) a try; hopefully, Impala will realise that no sorting is required. I did try (2), but that doesn't improve anything (the tables still get sorted, and since sorting is done in log-linear time, the time spent sorting is more or less  the same). Thanks!